# Find the pdf of X from its characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

the characteristic function of a random variable X is:

$$\Phi_X(\omega)=1-|\omega|\;\text{for}\;|\omega|<1$$ $$\Phi_X(\omega)=0\;\text{for}\;|\omega|>1$$

How to find the pdf of X?

I have started by using the Fourier transform inversion formula
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\Phi_X(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}d\omega$$
how to do the rest? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The integration is not difficult directly using integration by parts, but if you know the characteristic function of a uniform distribution then you can cheat, since going from the characteristic function to the pdf is similar to going in the other direction, and your characteristic function looks like the pdf of a triangular distribution which is the difference between  two uniform distributions.  Your result may involve $\cos(x)$ and $\frac1{x^2}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108138/321264