# Find characteristic function of the law with density $\max(1-|x|,0)$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I would like to get some feedback and hints for my answer below:

The problem is from a textbook I'm reading: problem 3.2.7 of [Probability Theory Lecture Notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JeBUquZ5BwVlV1dEpsTHVVbTA/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-5xbvKhDXZjrYRLfqppsHuQ) by Panchenko. Here's the question:

> Find the characteristic function of the law on $\mathbb{R}$ with
> density $\max(1-|x|,0)$. Then use the Fourier transform formula to
> conclude that $\max(1-|t|,0)$ is a characteristic function of some
> distribution.

Here's my attempt:

The characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is defined by
$$f(t)= \mathbb{E} e^{itX}$$
Since
$$\max(1-|x|,0)= \begin{cases}
      1+x & \text{if } x\in (-1,0)\\
      1-x & \text{if } x\in (0,1)\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}  
      \end{cases}$$
so here
$$f(t)= \int_{(-1,0)}e^{itx}(1+x)dx+ \int_{(0,1)}e^{itx}(1-x)dx$$

which after some calculations is
$$f(t)= -(\frac{e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2}}{t})^2 = \frac{1}{t^2}(2-e^{-it}-e^{it})=  \frac{4}{t^2} \sin^2(t/2)$$

Next, fourier inversion formula says that if $\int|f(t)|dt<\infty$, then $\mathbb{P}$ has density
$$p(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int f(t)e^{-itx}dt$$
So, we substitute the characterisitc function found above and we get that
\begin{eqnarray}
  p(x) &=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{t^2}(2-e^{-it}-e^{it})e^{-itx} dt
 \end{eqnarray}

Now, this integral seems complicated and I don't see how it gives the answer. Is there a simpler way of showing what is required at the end?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108138/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom it seems like all the answers in the linked page try to use the fact that the fourier transform of a fourier transform is the function we began with, while I think here, we want to do this directly through computing the integral [thinking emoji]